# Значение и статус выражения "другое дело, что"

Tags: грамматика, фразеология, вводные-слова

Пример: *Надо бы это сделать.* ***Другое дело, что*** делать этого никто не будет.

Как разобрать это предложение (определить его вид)? Каково значение  выражения ***другое дело, что***, то есть какие у него синонимы? С другой стороны? Кажется, не очень подходит.

В Интернете предлагаются такие синонимы: *иное дело, другой разговор, иной коленкор.*

**И запятую не хочется ставить,** так как паузы нет перед ЧТО. Может быть, это уже устойчивое сочетание? **В справочнике сообщается, что запятая ставится,** но там приводятся другие союзы http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_178

И почему это наречное выражение, как там указано?

Comment: А я просто не способен прочитать "другое дело что" без обычной для союза **что** паузы (или даже чуть более сильной).

Comment: А я думаю, что паузы нет,  если только вы тире поставите, но тогда союз ЧТО надо будет убрать. А вот перед  ЕСЛИ тире можно поставить.

Answer (score 1):

"**Другое дело**" используется для противопоставления (здесь - *желаний и возможностей*). Выражение - да, наречное: на его месте можно наречие пристроить (здесь, например, "*парадоксально, что*"), хотя точно передать смысл одним словом не получится. Он здесь в том, что удручающий факт отсутствия желающих "сделать это" предлагается *рассматривать отдельно* от необходимости "сделать" (возможно, это удастся как-то преодолеть). Отсутствие же паузы для русской пунктуации давно не указ: нет правила, освобождающего от запятой, предписанной другим правилом (при подстановке наречия она явно нужна).

Comment: Alex_ander, спасибо за ответ, но некоторые вопросы остались неясными: 1) Именное сочетание "другое дело" как-то по форме мало напоминает наречие. 2) Это сложное предложение? СПП? К какому виду оно относится? 3) Можно заменить на "с другой стороны", или  это будет неточная по смыслу замена? 4) запятую надо объяснять грамматически, а ее отсутствие можно объяснить устойчивостью оборота. Возможная замена: в то же время делать это никто не будет. Можно обосновать так: оборот имеет значение "в то же время" и не обособляется

Comment: 1) Оно не напоминает наречие, но может быть им заменено, - другое дело, что мало синонимичных вариантов. 2) Думаю, что это СПП("Парадоксально (то обстоятельство), что..." "Уму непостижимо, что..."). 3) "С другой стороны" имеет смысл простой уступки (говорящий не настаивает на ранее сказанном, а здесь - наоборот, что-то подразумевает/готовит ему в подкрепление). 4) Запятая здесь присоединяет придаточное. В примере со "в то же время" без запятой изменяется смысл (выражение перестаёт быть вводным): в другое время кто-нибудь сделает.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваше мнение.